# Skip Lists: the probability that the maximum level of the list is a greater than k

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, probability, article, skip-lists

given the randomLevel() function:

```
enter code here

randomLevel()
    newLevel := 1
        --random() returns a random value in [0,1)
    while random() < p do
        newLevel := newLevel+1
    return min(newLevel,MaxLevel)
```

which is used to determine in the insertion of a node in what level he will get, according to pugh's article the probability that the maximum level of the list is a greater than k is equal to 1 - (1 - p^k )^n and the article also say this expression is at most np^k (and therefore the expected maximum level is at most L(n) + 1/(1-p), for those of you who know the article..).

I'm having serious trouble in understanding from where this number came from because all i can think of is that P(node in level j) = (p^j)*(1-p) => P(node in level greater than k) = 1 - sum(P(node in level i), i=1 to i=k) which than leads to P(maximum level > k) = P(one of the nodes in level > k) = n*P(node in level greater than k) = ... = n*(1+p*(p^k-1))

help ??? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that with `p = 0.5`, you have:

```
1/2 of the nodes at level 1
1/4 of the nodes at level 2
1/8 of the nodes at level 3
1/16 of the nodes at level 4
etc.
```

The probability of a node being at level `k` is 1/2 the probability of the node being at level `k-1`.

Or, using the notation you posted:

```
P(node in level greater than k) = 1 - sum(P(node in level i), i=1 to i=k)
```

So the probability of a node being at a level greater than 4, for example is:

```
= 1 - (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16)
= 1 - (8/16 + 4/16 + 2/16 + 1/16)
= 1 - 15/16
= 1/16
```